# Add expo to my react-native app already exists

Tags: react-native, native, radix, expo

I am working on a project already exists native base and I want to add expo to easily test my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to make a new Expo project and copy over all the JavaScript from your existing project.

There isn't a way to `react-native link expo` or anything like that right now. There might be in the future but even then that wouldn't enable the easy sharing that you want. To get that you need to just use the binary code included with Expo (which can do most things you want to do).

Here is more info: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/faq.html#how-do-i-get-my-existing-react-native-project-running-with-expo

Comment: @theram, do you know if now there is a way to add expo on a react native which already exists?

Comment: @JérômeW As of a little over a year ago, you can add any of the Expo modules to a RN app, and as of a few weeks ago, you can now use notifications and updates in that manner. Here is some more info:
https://blog.expo.io/you-can-now-use-expo-apis-in-any-react-native-app-7c3a93041331
https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-37-is-now-available-dd5770f066a6

Answer (score 2):

Expo can now be added to an existing project, run the following command for automatic installation:

`npx install-expo-modules@latest`

If the command fails, you can refer to the [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/) for manual installation instructions.